# XmlReader testing of string returned for newline

Tags: c#, xml, newline, xmlreader

I am writing a C# class to use for generating email lists to use when a process either succeeds or fails. In running through XmlReader examples from the web, I found that validating the Read() is tougher than it looks.

I can use string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) to test for a null value or and empty node, but it will still blow by that test showing a "\n " in the tooltip for x. Testing for "\n ", '\n ', '\n'. "\n" or char(13) all fail. If I use x.Contains((char)13), it always find it and goes into the code trying to build the email address list. So far, it either always fails or always succeeds.

I found some old posts on stackoverflow where it seemed like the question was the same, but my results don't match with the answers. My environment is Windows 8.1 running Visual Studio 2013 with .Net Framework 4.51. The example from the web I was trying to make work before using the solution in my class is at [Microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

My conversion is below:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace XMLDemo
{
    public class project
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string uri = @"C:\\events\items.xml";
            string process_state = "Item";
            string emails = StreamEmailAddress(uri, process_state);
        }

        private static string StreamEmailAddress(string uri, string process_state)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(uri, settings);
            string returnValue  = "";

            reader.MoveToContent();
            while (reader.Read()) 
            {
                string x = reader.Value;
                if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) == false) && (x.Contains((char)13)))
                {
                    returnValue = returnValue + x + "; ";
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Made it to the end: " + returnValue);
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how your xml looks?

Comment: The logic in your sample code seems flawed. It should be `&& !x.Contains`.

Comment: 1) You should skip nodes whose [`XmlReader.NodeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.nodetype.aspx) is [`XmlNodeType.Whitespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodetype.aspx).  Check for `XmlNodeType.Text`, `XmlNodeType.CDATA` and maybe `XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace`.  2) Unless your XML file is enormous, don't use this approach, use [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Comment: Can't upvote you as my reputation isn't high enough, but you came to the same conclusion I did.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: After futzing with it all day, I looked at it with slightly fresher eyes after posting and saw the blatant error. I was using the incorrect function and trying to resolve line feeds by myself. By replacing IsNullOrEmpty(x) with IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x), I got the string of data as expected. Doing the code with email addresses will be easy now.